# Concerning cycles and group actions.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Here is the problem that I have.

Let $C=\{a=(ijkl)\}$ be the set of all cycles of length 4 in the symmetric group $S_4$. $S_4$ acts on the set $C$ by conjugation. For every cycle $a\in C$ determine the stabilizer in $S_4$. Are they all conjugated?

I think I am missing something here, as $C$ is of length 4, so there is no way that $gag^{-1}=a$ where $a\in C$ and $g\in S_4$.

EDIT: As one of the guys in comments section said, $a\in stab_{S_4}(a)$ and as stabilizer is a group, we have $a^2, a^3 \in stab_{S_4}(a)$. Until now, I have $stab_{S_4}(a)\in \{e, a, a^2, a^3\}$. Is there any other permutation in stab? I don't want to check all 24 permutations, as it is not interesting.

Comment: As a counter example, if $a \in C$, then $a$ stabilises $C$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 oh yeah, missed that but is it only $a$ and $e$? It seems weird because this was in an exam that I had and it would be too short/simple for an exam problem.

Comment: Well there's also $a^2$ and $a^3$.

Comment: You get $6$ distinct conjugates by permuting the $j,k,l$ in the cycle $(ijkl)$, and $6 \times 4 = 24$, so it looks like you have the whole stabilizer.

Comment: @DerekHolt I don't think I understood. Sorry for the lack of experience/practice but what does $4$ represent in $6*4=24$?

Comment: $4$ represents the number of elements in the stabilizer that you have found so far. You must surely know that size of orbit times size of stabilizer = size of group?

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks, I now do understand. You should write an answer so I can accept.